# How to Detect Power Mode for Android 10 on Samsung S20 FE 5G

Tags: android

I can see for this phone that I can manually choose between "High Performance", "Optimised", "Medium Power Saving", "Maximum Powers Saving" under Settings->Device Care->Battery->Power Mode.

However when I run the code :

```
    PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager)getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    boolean powerSaveMode = powerManager.isPowerSaveMode();
    if (powerSaveMode)
        Toast.makeText(thisContext, "Power Saver Mode is on", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    else
        Toast.makeText(thisContext, "Power Saver Mode is off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

it always returns "Power Save Mode is Off" regardless of the setting.

This code works fine on a Samsung S7 (Android 8 api 25) so I am guessing that "isPowerSaveMode()" is no longer the method I should be using for Q onwards.

Trouble is - I cannot find any documentation that tells me what to use now.

Also when I try :

```
    final String result = android.provider.Settings.System.getString(getContentResolver(), "psm_switch");
    Toast.makeText(thisContext, "psm_switch = " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It just returns "psm_switch = null"

Any help very gratefully received.
Many thanks
Tony

Thanks for the link.
We have an app that needs to track remote workers for signs of life - it records gps and accelerometer every 10 minutes.
There are a number of settings they need to get right (as in the link you gave us) but often get wrong.
I am attempting to add a status screen to the app which will read back to them all the settings that may cause their app to sleep or fail to collect / send gps data.
The two main offenders are the app being power optimised and giving location permission only when the app is in use.
General power optimising is also a candidate for problems and I am attempting to report that as well.
However, under Android 10 there does not appear to be a detectable setting to indicate if there is any level of power saving - only a collection of about 10 other settings. (such as background location enables)

Comment: As you are asking about battery/power management, unclear if you are aware of https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Comment: Just FYI, if you are using company devices have you considered Android Enterprise Mobility Management(EMM) also known as Mobility Device Management(MDM) as there are policies for [Android EMM - Advanced Location Sharing](https://developers.google.com/android/work/requirements#4.16.-advanced-location-sharing-management_1) but may depend on provider/device.

Comment: Thanks for the lead - I will read up on EMM